# How to make accordion compatible with IE9?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, accordion

The code was taken from here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

It works in IE 11 and IE 10 but the client wants it also to work in IE9.

I know...help me god!

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does client know that even Microsoft stopped supporting IE9 many years ago? They no longer  support IE10 either

Comment: Yes, they do know but unfortunately due to some ancient systems some 2% of users still need it to work on IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works in IE9 ... classList dose not support in IE 9

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  
  
  if (this.classList) {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
} else {
  // For IE9
  var classes = this.className.split(" ");
  var i = classes.indexOf("active");

  if (i >= 0)
    classes.splice(i, 1);
  else
    classes.push("active");
    this.className = classes.join(" ");
}
  
  
    //this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It opens the tab indeed but the icons do not work. There is also a simpler way just to open the tab on IE9 and that is to change this line: this.classList.toggle("active"); to this : this.className += " active";  but the icons do not work.

Comment: please check it again

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the `classList` property [is not supported in IE9](https://caniuse.com/classlist).

You need to add a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for it to work.

Comment: I tried changing this line:  this.classList.toggle("active");  to this :  this.className += " active";   and it opens the tab. But then the icons no longer switch. Is there a way to fix the icons?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you can use Jquery and Juqery UI; you cat do it same as follow and it works on IE9.

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```